# Is this a correct derivation of Peirce's law?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

I've used the rules of Chapter 2 of van Dalen's *Logic and Structure*, which allows only $\{ \wedge I, \wedge E, \to I, \to E, \bot E, RAA.\}$
$$
\newcommand{\bfrac}[2]{\displaystyle\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}}
\cfrac{
\cfrac{
\cfrac{{\bfrac{}{[( P\to Q)\to P]^3}} \quad\quad\quad \cfrac{[Q]^1}{P\to Q}}{P} \quad\quad\quad \bfrac{}{ {[\neg P]^2} }} {{\cfrac{\cfrac{\bot}{ \neg Q}1 \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad \bfrac{}{[ Q] ^1}} {\cfrac{\bot}{P}}}}}
{(P\to Q)\to P)\to P}3
$$

Comment: Please review your use of MathJax

Comment: Are you sue this is how it is supposed to be written? It's a tad bit hard to read.

Comment: No; the "lower" assumption of $Q$ is not correctly discharged.

Comment: I've just edited. mathjax doesn't support proof tree, so i can't choose another way to proof except the method to use cfrac.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2192230/troubles-with-proving-the-following-expression-p-implies-q-implies-p-imp): you need Double Negation.

Comment: Thank you, Mauro ALLEGRANZA.

Comment: Yes, now you derivation is perfect. Just add 2 next to the RAA inference rule deriving $P$ and discharging $\lnot P$, so that it's explicit where the assumption $\lnot P$ has been discharged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think below is the most natural way for me to derive Peirce's law in classic logic per Dalen's natural deduction rules and style. Another style is Fitch which I found an old post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2154958/using-the-fitch-system-how-do-i-prove-p-implies-q-implies-p-implies-p) deriving the same Peirce's law in Fitch style, and the steps are essentially same as mine below.

Please note that in your derivation you need to assume Q (your assumption #1) which is not needed at all in the whole proof. Actually if you transform your own proof to Fitch, then you'll see you cannot arrive at your first $\bot$ above at all within a same subproof. IMHO, Dalen's style is error prone and not suitable for new students just beginning their logic study. You *seem* to be able to do the job with discharging all assumptions, but you also intuitively feel you're not confident at all.

$$
\cfrac{[(P \to Q) \to P]^1 \quad \quad \cfrac{\cfrac{\cfrac{[\neg P]^2 \quad \quad [P]^3}{\bot} \to E}{Q} \bot}{(P \to Q)} \to I_3}{\cfrac{\cfrac{\cfrac{P}{\bot} \to E}{P} \quad RAA_2}
{((P \to Q) \to P) \to P} \to I_1} \to E
$$

Answer (score 0):

Using a form of natural deduction (screen print from my proof checker):

[image]
[image]